# SLADP configuration error message

Tags: 20.04

Following these [instructions](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/service-ldap):

[image: terminal-screenshot]

Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS

Comment: There is a typo in your command: `slapd` is not `slpad`.  Besides, is is better to copy/paste text than images.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please read [why we ask that you not post text as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11810933).  Please 

[Edit your post](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1507484/edit)

to include the text in-addition-to or in-place-of the image.  Thanks!